# Create Colour in InDesign CS5 with CMYK values from user input

Tags: colors, applescript, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to create a script which, in the process of opening a template file, asks the user for a set of CMYK values.

The idea is to then either change the value of an existing colour (called "Primary Colour") therefore changing the colour of every item to which it is applied...or add this new colour and delete 'Primary Colour' replacing it with new colour.

The problem is I can't get past creating a new colour with user input values. I can create a new colour with;

```
 set New_Swatch to make color with properties {name:"New Primary Colour", model:process, color value:{82,72,49,46}}
```

however as soon as I try to replace the color value with a variable I get the error;

"Adobe InDesign CS5 got an error: Invalid parameter."

Here is a snippet of code in context;

```
set primaryColour to text returned of (display dialog "Enter CMYK calues of Primary Colour (separated by commas e.g. 0,0,0,0)" default answer "") as string

tell application "Adobe InDesign CS5"
 activate
 tell active document
    set New_Swatch to make color with properties {name:"new", model:process, color value:primaryColour}
  end tell
end tell
```

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently use this:

```
set primaryColor to text returned of (display dialog "Enter CMYK values of Primary Colour (separated by commas e.g. 0,0,0,0)" default answer "") as string
set text item delimiters to ","
set colorvalue to {}
repeat with color from 1 to count of text items of primaryColor
   copy (text item colour of primaryColor as number) to end of colorvalue
end repeat
  set colorname to "TEST"
tell application "Adobe InDesign CS5"
   activate
   tell active document
    set newcolor to make color with properties {name:colorname, space:CMYK, model:process, color value:colorvalue}
   end tell
end tell
```

Why? Because it works. It is not pretty and it was not my first, or even 10th method to get the job done...Why this works? No idea...

It just does. You would think that:

```
  set text item delimiters to ","
  set {C,M,Y,K} to text items of primaryColor
```

...

```
  set newcolor to make color with properties {name:colorname, space:CMYK, model:process, color value:{C,M,Y,K}}
```

Would do the trick, but it doesn't... I'm sure your attempts so far have proven just how much of a pain this particular function is.

Comment: The method of using the color picker by Simon will take CMYK values, convert them to RGB, then make CMYK in the end. The values entered by the user does not match the end result.

Comment: Thank you Lithodora so much...this was really starting to make me bang my head off the desk! I had a feeling the cause of my original error was because the values returned were not encased in {curly brackets} so the set colorvalue to {} was something I doubt I would've thought of. I also note your comment regarding @Simon White...Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to use the AppleScript “choose color” command, which presents a color picker, rather than presenting your user with a dialog into which they have to enter numeric color values.

This example inserts RGB colors as text into a BBEdit window, but you would use the same principle to insert CMYK colors as text into InDesign.

```
tell application "BBEdit"
    activate
    set theColorValues to choose color
    set theR to round (the first item of theColorValues) / 257
    set theG to round (the second item of theColorValues) / 257
    set theB to round (the third item of theColorValues) / 257
    set theRGBColor to "rgb(" & theR & ", " & theG & ", " & theB & ")"
    set selection to theRGBColor
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Simon. I've a felling this will become useful for something else I have lined up!

Answer (score -1):

set primaryColor to text returned of (display dialog "Enter CMYK values of Primary Color (separated by commas e.g. 0,0,0,0)" default answer "") as string

set text item delimiters to ","

set colorvalue to {}

repeat with color from 1 to count of text items of primaryColor
copy (text item color of primaryColor as number) to end of colorvalue

end repeat

set colorname to primaryColor

tell application "Adobe InDesign CC 2017"

activate

tell active document

set newcolor to make color with properties {name:colorname, space:CMYK, model:process, color value:colorvalue}

end tell

end tell